# How to get eventbrite attendees with app_key?

Tags: eventbrite

I'm trying to get the attendees for an event I've created with
https://www.eventbrite.com/json/event_list_attendees?app_key=MYAPPKEY&id=MYEVENTID

However it fails with an error:

```
{"error": {"error_type": "Not Found", "error_message": "Invalid email and/or password."}}
```

In the example, I've replaced the app_key and id, but they are valid.  If I change them to invalid values I get "This application key is not valid." and "No such event. [XXX]"

Since the event was created by the same account as I requested the app_key from I assume I should be able to retrieve attendees.

Answer (score 0):

See the [API Authentication page](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication/).  You'll need to supply user credentials (in addition to your developer key) when accessing this API method.